# Showing the inequality for $L^2( \mu)$ function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

This is the problem from analysis. (In Lebesgue theory).

Question : Suppose $\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f|^2 d \mu < \infty$. Show that $\mu (\{x \in \mathbb R^n  | |f(x)|>a\})\leq \frac{1}{a^2} \int_{\mathbb R^n} |f|^2 d\mu$.

I tried to solve it using Bessel's inequality...but it is not quite clear... How can I solve it?

Comment: Consider $\int_{E_a}|f(x)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x$ where $E_a=\{x:|f(x)|\ge a\}$ in comparison to $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x)|^2\,\mathrm{d}x$  and in comparison to $a^2|E_a|$.

Comment: Ah, so $a^2 |E_a| = \int_{E_a} a^2 d\mu \leq \int_{E_a} |f|^2 d\mu \leq \int_{R^n} |f|^2 d\mu$. right? It was obvious question :(

Comment: As a side note in probability theory it is called Bienaymé-Tchebychev inequality..

Answer (score 1):

**Chebyshev's Inequality**

This is known as [Chebyshev's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality).

Let $E_a=\{x:|f(x)|\ge a\}$, then for $p\gt0$
$$
a^p|E_a|\le\int_{E_a}|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm{d}x\le\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1
$$
Thus,
$$
|E_a|\le\frac1{a^p}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2
$$
For your inequality, take $p=2$.

---

**Slightly Better Result**

If $f\in L^p$,
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{E_a}|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm{d}x=0\tag3
$$
Thus, using the left hand inequality from $(1)$, in addition to $(2)$, we get that
$$
\lim_{a\to\infty}a^p|E_a|=0\tag4
$$